# why does my audit ban increase despite passing dozens of audits since my last failure?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

Ask Ubuntu user here.

Recently I was banned for 7 days from reviewing. I know that particular post was audit and I clicked on <kbd>Edit</kbd>

( I know it was better to use delete than edit- but I thought I can use  <kbd>Edit</kbd> button for such audits to pass )

Previously I was banned for 2 days. After that till today I am sure **I passsed dozens of audits and no single audit fail**

My question:

Why the ban has increased from 2d to 7d, even I passed  dozens of audits since my last failure ?

Ban for only single audit fail ?

Comment: Isn't this better asked on the meta of Ask Ubuntu? The mods there can see your failed audits and explain what happened and what is expected.

Comment: @rene Well, I asked one of the mod in chat, he verified my review history and conformed that I have passed many audits.

Comment: @rene - AU mod here - I've looked and cannot explain - can only see two audit failures a month apart with dozens of successful audits in between.  Q is probably more general - why does the length of audit ban increase despite successfully passing lots of audits in the interim.

Comment: OK, fair enough. maybe add that comment in the question.

Comment: AFAIK, those review bans have always been progressive in lengths. So if you have been banned once for 2 days, the next ban will be 7 days, no matter what happened. After this you're in for a 30 days ban.

Comment: @ShadowWizard The answer to the post mentions "The ban was caused by multiple audit failures, not just a single failure". But I was not failed many atleast

Comment: It might depend on the type of audit you failed. Was the post a spam post maybe?

Comment: @rene [this](http://askubuntu.com/review/low-quality-posts/484540) is the audit.I don't think it was a spam.

Comment: @rene - yeah - someone flagged it as spam.  Marked as helpful and then subsequently cleared.  So kind of harsh to increase to increase the audit ban.  I'll clear you from being banned Ravan.  There definitely looks like a system issue here.

Comment: Ok, I apologize on behalf of the spam hunters in the Tavern, but [this](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=3046166#3046166) might have set it off. Do know that we have seen a barrage of spam seeds for *Path too Long*  tools that are a known scam. Sometimes we flag wrong. I think the clearance from @fossfreedom is legit and we're sorry for the trouble this caused to you.

Comment: The review ban is "cross queue", you probably failed in other queue and forgot.

Comment: @ShadowWizard "other queue"-- no. I am pretty sure. AFAIK If I was failed, immediately it will show message like "__Stop Listen...__". But I didn't see any such message in any _other queue_.